# Why Rcpp code is much slowly than raw R code

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to implement RRHO analysis described in this manuscript https://academic.oup.com/nar/article/38/17/e169/1033168,
Maybe it's more clear and easy to see following R code to implement RRHO analysis. `calculate_hyper_overlap` function is what I try to do.

```
## Compute the overlaps between two *character* atomic vector:
hyper_test <- function(sample1, sample2, n) {
    count <- length(intersect(sample1, sample2))
    m <- length(sample1)
    k <- length(sample2)
    # under-enrichment
    if (count <= m * k / n) {
        sign <- -1L
        pvalue <- stats::phyper(
            q = count, m = m, n = n - m,
            k = k, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE
        )
    } else {
        # over-enrichment
        sign <- 1L
        pvalue <- stats::phyper(
            q = count, m = m, n = n - m,
            k = k, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = FALSE
        )
    }

    c(count = count, pvalue = pvalue, sign = sign)
}

calculate_hyper_overlap <- function(sample1, sample2, n, stepsize) {
    row_ids <- seq.int(stepsize, length(sample1), by = stepsize)
    col_ids <- seq.int(stepsize, length(sample2), by = stepsize)
    indexes <- expand.grid(
        row_ids = row_ids,
        col_ids = col_ids
    )
    overlaps <- apply(as.matrix(indexes), 1L, function(x) {
        hyper_test(
            sample1[seq_len(x[["row_ids"]])],
            sample2[seq_len(x[["col_ids"]])],
            n = n
        )
    }, simplify = FALSE)
    overlaps <- data.table::transpose(overlaps)
    number_of_obj <- length(row_ids)
    matrix_counts <- matrix(
        overlaps[[1L]],
        nrow = number_of_obj
    )
    matrix_pvals <- matrix(
        overlaps[[2L]],
        nrow = number_of_obj
    )
    matrix_signs <- matrix(
        overlaps[[3L]],
        nrow = number_of_obj
    )
    list(
        counts = matrix_counts,
        pvalue = matrix_pvals,
        signs = matrix_signs
    )
}
```

The Rcpp code I use is here:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List calculate_hyper_overlap_cpp(CharacterVector sample1, CharacterVector sample2, int n, int stepsize)
{
    int list1_len = floor((sample1.size() - stepsize) / stepsize) + 1;
    int list2_len = floor((sample2.size() - stepsize) / stepsize) + 1;
    IntegerMatrix counts(list1_len, list2_len);
    NumericMatrix pvalue(list1_len, list2_len);
    IntegerMatrix signs(list1_len, list2_len);
    for (int i = 0; i < list1_len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < list2_len; j++)
        {
            CharacterVector list1 = sample1[Range(0, (i + 1) * stepsize - 1)];
            CharacterVector list2 = sample2[Range(0, (j + 1) * stepsize - 1)];
            int count = intersect(list1, list2).size();
            counts(i, j) = count;
            int m = list1.size(), k = list2.size();
            if (count <= m * k / n)
            // under-enrichment
            {
                pvalue(i, j) = R::phyper(count, m, n - m, k, true, false);
                signs(i, j) = -1;
            }
            else
            // over-enrichment
            {
                pvalue(i, j) = R::phyper(count, m, n - m, k, false, false);
                signs(i, j) = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return List::create(Named("counts") = counts,
                        Named("pvalue") = pvalue,
                        Named("signs") = signs);
}
```

here is the test:

```
n <- 200
sample1 <- rnorm(n)
sample2 <- rnorm(n)
names(sample1) <- names(sample2) <- paste0("gene", seq_len(n))
bench_res <- bench::mark(
    res1 <- calculate_hyper_overlap_cpp(
        names(sample1), names(sample2),
        n = n, stepsize = 3L
    ),
    res2 <- calculate_hyper_overlap(
        names(sample1), names(sample2),
        n = n, stepsize = 3L
    ),
    check = FALSE
)
dplyr::select(bench_res, where(~ !is.list(.x)))
```

The test results

[image: 1]

The first line is the time by Rcpp code and the second by raw R code

Comment: Thanks @ZheyuanLi, I'm firstly using the Rcpp, the `floor`, `intersect` function comes from Rcpp suger? I just think them as cpp function, I'll try find similar function in raw cpp. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thanks for your advice, I find this function in this book <https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/300_Rmath.html> which indicates the function in the `R::` namespace in Rcpp is written in C language. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: `R::phyper` is one of many of the (scalar) d/q/pr/r function for various distributions that R offers at the _C_ level and which Rcpp offers as C++ accessors for convenience.  You generally can also get them via Rcpp Sugar in a vectorized form.

Comment: I think the long and short of it is that you demonstrated that is it is entirely possible to write equally slow code in C++ -- "everything is always problem-dependent". You need to profile.  Maybe the bulk of the time is spent in `sample()` and then it does not matter if you call from R or C++?

Comment: Really appreciate you @DirkEddelbuettel, For my problem, it may be more appropriate to use R code ?

Comment: It's hard to say without a closer look for which I don't have time now / for which the example isn't quite as minimal as we'd like.  I *really* recommend the profiling tools.  See where either R or C++ spends a bulk of time and try to improve that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DirkEddelbuettel, I'll try to find other ways to optimize this, since I need permutation 1000 times to calculate the overall P-value, which consume a lot of time.